# Return Columns as Rows for Single Record

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, unpivot

I've read many posts on this site as well as others regarding using PIVOT, UNPIVOT, UNION and CROSS JOIN but I can't quite seem to get the results I'm looking for.

My table looks like the following:

```
EmployeeName    Salary  Address             City        State   Zip     AdditionalDetails
=========================================================================================
Doe, John       400000  111 Jackson Ave     Nowhere     CA      99999   Reliable 
Blow, Joe       300000  222 Johnson St      Somewhere   ME      00000   Always late
```

What I'm trying to show is the following:

```
EmployeeName        Doe, John
Salary              400000
Address             111 Jackson Ave
City                Nowhere
State               CA
Zip                 99999
AdditionalDetails   Reliable
```

The closest I've come is using UNPIVOT as follows, however, the issue is that the two columns are transposed, I need to swap them though I'm not sure how to do that.

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT EmployeeName, Salary, Address, City, State, Zip, AdditionalDetails
    FROM EmployeeDetails
    WHERE EmployeeDetails.EmployeeID=@EmployeeID
) AS SourceTable
UNPIVOT
(
    Value FOR Header IN
    (EmployeeName, Salary, Address, City, State, Zip, AdditionalDetails)
) AS UnpivotTable
```

So what I'm getting is:

```
Value           Header
Doe, John       EmployeeName
400000          Salary
111 Jackson Ave Address
Nowhere         City
CA              State
99999           Zip
Reliable        AdditionalDetails
```

How do I get the data displayed as I need it? I will start by saying that there will only ever be a single employee record returned at a time with this query. I'm appending this data into a CSV and its a request that the employee record be displayed this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there:

The code you have is :

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT EmployeeName, Salary, Address, City, State, Zip, AdditionalDetails
    FROM EmployeeDetails
    WHERE EmployeeDetails.EmployeeID=@EmployeeID
) AS SourceTable
UNPIVOT
(
    Value FOR Header IN
    (EmployeeName, Salary, Address, City, State, Zip, AdditionalDetails)
) AS UnpivotTable
```

You should have :

```
SELECT Header, Value
FROM
(
    SELECT EmployeeName, Salary, Address, City, State, Zip, AdditionalDetails
    FROM EmployeeDetails
    WHERE EmployeeDetails.EmployeeID=@EmployeeID
) AS SourceTable
UNPIVOT
(
    Value FOR Header IN
    (EmployeeName, Salary, Address, City, State, Zip, AdditionalDetails)
) AS UnpivotTable
```

The results:

[image]